# Merge and One-to-Many objects

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

У меня есть 2 сущности

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "block")
public class Block {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long id_block;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Subblock> subblock = new ArrayList<>();


    public Block() {

    }

    public long getId_block() {
        return id_block;
    }

    public void setId_block(long id_block) {
        this.id_block = id_block;
    }

    public Block(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public List<Subblock> getSubblock() {
        return subblock;
    }

    public void setSubblock(List<Subblock> subblock) {
        this.subblock = subblock;
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "subblock")
public class Subblock {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long id_subblock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_block")
    private Block block;


    @Column
    String name;

    public Subblock() {
    }

    public long getId_subblock() {
        return id_subblock;
    }

    public void setId_subblock(long id_subblock) {
        this.id_subblock = id_subblock;
    }


    public Block getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public void setBlock(Block block) {
        this.block = block;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Сервис который осуществляет запись обьекта в бд

```
@Service
public class RatingService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ;
    @Autowired
    StaticDataDAO staticDataDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Block block){
        staticDataDAO.addBlock(block);
    }

}
```

И главный метод

```
Block block = new Block();
        Subblock subblock = new Subblock();

        List<Subblock>subblockList= new ArrayList();

        subblock.setName(messageSource.getMessage("block_1.1",new String[]{},locale));
        subblockList.add(subblock);

        block.setName(messageSource.getMessage("block_1",new String[]{},locale));
        block.setSubblock(subblockList);
        try {
                ratingService.add(block);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Но по чему-то в базе поле в таблице Subblock.id_block остается пустым , хотя с помощью mappedBY я связываю класы.

Comment: У тебя [bidirectional OneToMany](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional), похоже, ты упустил "утилитные" методы (посмотри по ссылке...).

Comment: Но почему-то при `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_block")
    private List<Subblock> subblock = new ArrayList<>();
     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_block") 
    private Block block;`
Все работает отлично и при merge(Block) в subblock.id_block правильно появляется ссылка на block.id_block